# Remove all the onclick under TR

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove all the `onclick`s under specific `tr`..

For example,

before:

```
<tr id="current">
   <td onclick="foo();"></td>
   <td onclick="foo();"><div onclick="abc();"></div></td>
   <td onclick="foo();"></td>
   <td onclick="foo();"></td>
</tr>
```

after:

```
<tr id="current">
   <td></td>
   <td><div></div></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
</tr>
```

I think I have to do something like:

```
$("#current td").each(function() {
   $(this).removeAttr('onclick');
});

$("#current td div").each(function() {
   $(this).removeAttr('onclick');
});
```

but maybe there is another option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$("#current").find("*").off();
```

`find("*")` will find all the elements contained in `#current`. This is then enough to remove all the onclick events (both `<td>` and `<div>`).

Comment: Actually, even "each" shouldn't be required here: `$("#current td").off();`, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Use [unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) to remove a attached event handler from the element.

```
$( "#current td").unbind( "click" );
```

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements."

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `onclick` attribute to empty string:

```
$("#current td").attr("onclick","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#current").each(function() {
   $(this).unbind("click");
});
```

[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#current td").prop("disabled",true);
```